# Двигаю Label по горизонтали, он оставляет за собой след. Как убрать шлейф?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios7

```
float x = [self xPositionFromSliderValue:self.navigationSlider];
   UILabel* label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 42, 30, 20)];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.494 green:0 blue:0.835 alpha:1]];
    [label setText:_playTimer.text];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setText:_playTimer.text];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:12]];
    [self.navigationSlider addSubview:label];
```

Вот таким образом двигаю Label, он оставляет за собой шлейф. Как его убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не двигаете `UILabel`, вы создаете новые и кладете их на новую позицию, так что это не совсем шлейф, это прост старые `UILabel`

Чтобы двигать визуальный объект попробуйте сохранить указатель на него

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel *label;
```

потом двигаем

```
self.label.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
```

Чтобы двигать объект с анимацией, поместите код перемещения в блок анимации:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2 animations:^{
    self.label.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
} completion:nil];
```